# Community Moderator Elections: Can we get a subscription notification when each phase starts?

Tags: feature-request, election, subscription

I am new to the concept of these moderator elections. Is there any way I can subscribe to all all flavors of Stack Exchange websites for moderator elections? There is a badge `caucus`— "Visited an election during any phase of an active election". That's how I learned there elections exist.

Comment: For linking purposes: [Re-adding Election Notices to System Messages](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/434269)

Comment: Don't we already get notifications for the nomination and election phases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are eligible to participate in an election phase, you get a notification in your global inbox on the site, no sign-up required.

Elections are also announced on the site's meta, in the community bulletin board on the site, and (sometimes, but we're trying to avoid it) in a system message banner.

There is no way right now to be notified of elections on *any* site, and I'm not sure what the point would be. Moderator elections are largely an internal matter on the site. They sometimes attract spectators from other sites, but for the most part, they're pretty self-contained.

You can read the gory details about the election setup and process [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) and see past (and current, though right now there aren't any) elections across the network [here](http://elections.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Note that you can also subscribe to email notifications for your global inbox, if you want more intrusive notifications of such things.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is watch for posts tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election) on every meta site; you'll get other random posts about elections, and won't get one notification per phase, but you will hear about every election since they get [mentioned](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/2012-community-moderator-election) on meta. There's a filter [here](https://stackexchange.com/filters/22998/elections) you can watch (which is how I found this post in the first place)